# #pragma region ... on the mac / Xcode

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, pragma

In Visual Studio 2010/2012 I use the following "pragma" to create collapsible sections in my code, it helps a lot to navigate.

```
#pragma region Section Title
...
#pragma endregion
```

The problem is that I have a lot of "warning" because the compiler does not recognize the pragma !

I  know that Xcode support other "similar" pragma, like #pragma mark !

But is there a way (by using a macro ?) to allow my Mac to compile this code without the warning and keep the pragma ?

Comment: Which Xcode version do you use? My Xcode 4.6.3 compiles that without any problems. Unknown pragmas are ignored, either silently or with a warning, depending on the build settings.

Comment: As @MartinR said, that should just compile - are you sure the reason it doesn't compile is not somewhere else? Does the error message explicitly mention that `#pragma`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late answer... it is not an error, but a warning. I'm looking for a way to remove this warning because there are too much warning with theses pragmas. Do you know a way please ?